# Expectation from CDF question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

Trying to do this (sorry for the formatting)

$X$ is a random variable with this cdf:

$$
F_X(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x<-3 \\
            \frac{1}{6}x+\frac{1}{2}  & \quad -3\le x<0 \\
            \frac{1}{2} & \quad 0\le x<1 \\
            1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x+1}  & \quad x\ge 1.
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Find $E(X)$

I've tried it in two different ways and I keep getting $0$ as answer, but apparently that's wrong.  I tried doing this for instance:
$$(-3)\left(\frac{1}{6}(-3) + \frac{1}{2}\right) + 1\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-1+1}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right) $$

Comment: Your definition of $X$ doesn't seem to be correct, as the bounds on $X$ depend on $X$ itself.

Comment: If the answer provided is correct, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the probability density function, $f(x)$, to calculate the expectation using
$$ E(x) = \int x f(x) dx $$

We can get $f(x)$ from the cumulative density function by differentiating in each region:
$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x<-3 \\
            \frac{1}{6}  & \quad -3\le x<0 \\
            0 & \quad 0\le x<1 \\
            \frac{1}{2}e^{-x+1}  & \quad x\ge 1.
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Note that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 1$$ as required.

Then, we plug $f(x)$ into the equation for $E(x)$ and compute the integral piecewise:
$$ E(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{-3} x \cdot 0 dx + \int_{-3}^0 x\cdot \frac{1}{6} dx + \int_{0}^{1} x \cdot 0 dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} x \cdot \frac{1}{2}\exp(1-x)dx$$

Simplifying, we obtain
$$ E(x) = \left[\frac{x^2}{12}\right]_{-3}^{0} - \left[\frac{(x+1)}{2}\cdot \exp(1-x)\right]_{1}^{\infty} $$
which gives
$$ E(x)= -\frac{3}{4} + 1 = \frac{1}{4} $$